# How to list the existing Components of a Folder using WebDAV URL in Tridion?

Tags: tridion

Can you please explain how to get the list of Components in a Folder based on it's WebDAV URL in C# by using Tridion's TOM.NET API.

Comment: What API are you using? CoreService, TOM.NET, TOM?

Comment: List of components from webdav url of what? Folder?

Comment: I am using TOM.NET API.
I need to access the list of components from webdav url of a folder in TRIDION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var folder = (Folder) session.GetObject("/webdav/Test/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Templates");
var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(session);
var listXml = folder.GetListItems(filter);
```

The `GetItems` method will return you a list of objects while `GetListItems` returns an XML element. Depending on the version of Tridion you are using you might not have `GetItems` method implemented yet

You can set additional properties on filter variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is very help full for me. Also please tell me how to add additional filter parameters, as I am trying to list out the objects in the folder. Fast reply would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is my code::: Folder folder = (Folder)mySession.GetObject("/webdav/020%20Global%20Content/Building%20Blocks/Content/LookUp"); OrganizationalItemItemsFilter filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(mySession); filter.Recursive = true; //filter.ItemTypes = myLookUpComponent; List<RepositoryLocalObject> myLookComponentList = (List<RepositoryLocalObject>)folder.GetItems(filter);

Comment: Please check it , I am getting conversion error at last line.... Early response will be appreciated.

Comment: My folder consists only components, I am using sdl tridion 2011 sp1 version. If GetItems method is not implemented in this version, please give me an example how to use GetListItems... Replace the last line of my code with Getlistitems method...

Comment: @Murali GetListItems will just return you XML that you can handle as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
List<RepositoryLocalObject> myLookComponentList = 
     (List<RepositoryLocalObject>)folder.GetItems(filter).ToList();
```